# access ng-resource in function through $scope causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ngresource

I have a Rails app and access two models through the JSON API using ng-resource.

In my template I display a list of the first model "orders":

```
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
  Order {{order.id}}: 
  Product: {{showProduct(order.product_id)}}
</li>
```

Each "order" contains a `product_id`. Now I would like to access the second model ("products") and display inside the `ng-repeat` the correct "product" with the ID `product_id` of the corresponding "order".

To achieve that I thought of using a function `showProduct()` and use `order.product_id` as an argument. However when I do this it causes an infinite loop that keeps making GET requests to my database.

Here the important part of my **app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('shop', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('models', ['$resource', function($resource){
  var orders_model = $resource("/orders/:id.json", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}});
  var products_model = $resource("/products/:id.json", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}});

  var o = { 
    orders: orders_model,
    products: products_model
  };
  return o;
}]);

app.controller('OrdersCtrl', ['$scope', 'models', function($scope, models){
  $scope.orders = models.orders.query();

  $scope.showProduct = function(product_id){
    return models.products.get({id: product_id});
  };
}])
```

These are the errors in my console (which make sense since it's an infinite loop):

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

The GET request in the Rails console seems fine. Maybe I'm trying to think much more complicated than I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because you have `showProduct` in the view, the function is called on every digest, returning each time a different promise so it breaks:

- you create server requests several times per digest
- each request is different from the other
- 10 iterations are made until two values are equal or it throws an exception

I suggest you to do:

```
models.orders.query().$promise
  .then(function(orders){
    $scope.orders = orders;
    //using lodash here, I recommend you use it too
    _.each(orders, function(order){
      models.products.get({id: order.product_id }).$promise
        .then(function(product){
          order.product = product;
        })
    });
  });
```

And in the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="order in orders">
  Order {{order.id}}: 
  Product: {{order.product}}
</li>
```

---

But using this code will trigger one query for each order which is quite bad: its a N+1 anti pattern.

2 solutions:

- have the order include the product data directly
- have one single request with all product ids

Comment: Thank you very much! That works. How would I include the product data directly in the order?

Comment: depends how you create your json :) beware to use `includes` in your activerecord query to avoid the N+1 server side

Comment: I tried to include the products in the orders controller like this: `respond_with Order.includes(:product)`. But I still can't figure out how to access the products through Angular. 
In the code above I use ng-resource to access the controller and turn the orders into JSON

Comment: you must return product within order json

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to get my head around this topic for the first time. Can you specify how I would do that? I assume I have to add something to `$resource("/orders/:id.json",` ?

Comment: No, how do you create the json server side?

Comment: I'm using Rail's default `respond_to :json` at the top of the controller and in the index action I have `@orders = Order.includes(:product)` and `respond_with @orders`. Maybe the `includes` is not quite right?

Comment: Yes you have to change your controller code to write what you expect the json to be check http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json or even better use serializers like active model serializer

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying very similar things but didn't get it quite right. `Order.all.to_json(:include => :product)` did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I first felt that it should work. Anyway, if it does not then i would try it this way:

In your controller:

```
  $scope.showProduct = function(product_id){
    var product = models.products.get({id: product_id}, function(){
      return product;
    });
  };
```

This will return the value once the data arrived from the server.

Comment: It will be executed on each digest, so it will crash too